# How to create a plotly line plot from a pandas DataFrame with lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a pandas DataFrame created from a dict and would like to create a plotly line plot from it. The DataFrame contains lists however and looks like this:

```
                    a  ...                   L
0                 a_0  ...  [L_00,       L_01]
1                 a_1  ...  [L_10,       L_11]
2                 a_2  ...  [L_20,       L_21]
3                 a_3  ...  [L_30,       L_31]
```

My plot should be the values of `L_i0` plotted against `a_i` but I can only create the plot giving the name of a column like this:

```
fig = px.line(dataframe, x='a', y='L')
```

I know that I can access the values like this `['L'][i][0]` and then iterate over i but is it possible to tell plotly to take only the first values of the list L?

#### Sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],
                   'L':[[10,11,12], [20,21,22], [30,31,21]]})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had read the documentation wrong and found a way to do what I want to do:

```
fig = px.line(dataframe, x='a',
              y=[tupel[0] for tupel in dataframe['L']])
```

this accesses the first element in the lists which are tupels contained in L.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see why, but if it is in fact correct that you

> [...] can only create the plot giving the name of a column like this

Then you should really consider making sure that `df['L']` does in fact only contain the values you'd like to plot, and not lists with a bunch of other stuff. But you may very well have good reason to organize your data exactly the way you have, so I suspect your question is in fact an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

But if you're not bound to using `plotly.express`, then `plotly.graph_objects` can do exactly what you seem to aim for here using, among other things,  `df.iterrows()`. I'm assuming that this datastructure resembles your real world scenario:

```
   a        L
0  1  [10, 11, 12]
1  2  [20, 21, 22]
2  3  [30, 31, 21]
```

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],
                   'L':[[10,11,12], [20,21,22], [30,31,21]]})

aVals = []
LVals = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    aVals.append(row[0])
    LVals.append(row[1][0])
    
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=aVals, y=LVals))
fig.show()
```

#### Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**import the libraries**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
```

**creating dataframe using pandas**

```
data = [['DS', 'Linked_list', 10], ['DS', 'Stack', 9], ['DS', 'Queue', 7], 
        ['Algo', 'Greedy', 8], ['Algo', 'DP', 6], ['Algo', 'BackTrack', 5], ]  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Category', 'Name', 'Marks'])
```

**ploting the numeric columns**

```
plt.plot(df["Marks"])
plt.xlabel
```